# Windows command line - filter lines with non-zero values

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

I have a file.data whose content is as below:

```
140919071513,10,0,1,0,0
140919071513,11,0,1,0,0
140919071513,12,67,1,0,0
140919071513,13,89,1,0,0
140919071513,14,0,1,0,0
140919071513,15,32,1,0,0
140919071513,16,0,1,0,0
140919071513,17,0,1,0,0
140919071513,18,78,1,0,0
140919071513,19,0,1,0,0
140919071513,20,34,1,0,0
```

I need to run a **one-line command** in Windows-DOS to get the below output:

**(non-zero values in 3rd column)**

```
140919071513,12,67,1,0,0
140919071513,13,89,1,0,0
140919071513,15,32,1,0,0
140919071513,18,78,1,0,0
140919071513,20,34,1,0,0
```

I used this command to try to get something, but couldn't get the desired result.

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=," %i in file.data do echo %i
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research effort

Comment: I did some research, but couldn't get the desired result.

Comment: Is a solution in Powershell also "allowed"?

Comment: It's my client's terminal server with windows operating system. I don't think they have Powershell installed in it.

Comment: @Daniel i disagree. OP tried to figure it out him/her self and showed how far they got with their own solution

Comment: @TimothyGroote Fair enough. When I voted to close, the attempt had not been added to the question yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cmd.exe you can do the following:

```
for /f "tokens=1-3,* delims=," %i in (tst.txt) do @if %k GTR 0 echo %i,%j,%k,%l
```

Almost, what you tried, but a few changes:

```
... do @if ..// The @ will disable echo of the command itself ...
tokens=1-3,* // the first three tokens will be translated into variables
delims=,     // %i, %j and %k. The rest of each line ends up in %l

%k GTR 0     // GTR="greater", is a comparison of the third column against 0
```

This will get you

```
140919071513,12,67,1,0,0
140919071513,13,89,1,0,0
140919071513,15,32,1,0,0
140919071513,18,78,1,0,0
140919071513,20,34,1,0,0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this good description and the answer. take care.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the case that you have Powershell at hand:

```
Import-Csv .\file.data -Header "A","B","C","D","E","F"|where {$_.C -ne 0}|foreach-object {Write-host("$($_.A),$($_.B),$($_.C),$($_.D),$($_.E),$($_.F)")}
```

The last part with the "foreach-object {Write-Host..." might be optimized, but it works in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
findstr /v /r /c:"^[^,]*,[^,]*,0," file.data
```

This will list all the lines that does not match (`/v`) the regular expression (`/r`) : from the start of the line (`^`) any sequence of zero or more characters that does not contain a comma (`[^,]*`), followed by a comma, any sequence of zero or more characters that does not contain a comma, a comma, a zero and a comma.